# Youtube Data API v3 does not send nextPageToken on selecting fields in resource

Tags: python, youtube-data-api

I am using Youtube Data API v3 for fetching comments for a video. I followed official documentation https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list

Using `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?key=MY_KEY&videoId=ay4MKe1u7Ec&part=id,snippet,replies&maxResults=2`

I get

```
{
"kind": "youtube#commentThreadListResponse",
"etag": "\"RmznBCICv9YtgWaaa_nWDIH1_GM/lPy9jihUjGu4N-8qmo83AkMD81E\"",
"nextPageToken": "QURTSl9pMW1lUmhuMHNKaWVDQWhOUUs3UzltVWpEa3JBTW5VdTNQY3I2al9OMmg3VUhUcVRId0lRYkZwV0RiLWdGbG90d3lHQlhzT3dSUnVObmdmaEdpY0RCOGlqRnNUR0pUM05lenpsaVJCUkpFZUFlWDF0SVNyVGFNMURYZ3M=",
"pageInfo": {
"totalResults": 2,
"resultsPerPage": 2
},
"items": [
{
"kind": "youtube#commentThread",
"etag": "\"RmznBCICv9YtgWaaa_nWDIH1_GM/-srkOOUlK2u6VrOhrHLwNvW9uhY\"",
"id": "Ugwud1sVfboCaSWuyR54AaABAg",
"snippet": {
    "videoId": "ay4MKe1u7Ec",
    "topLevelComment": {
    "kind": "youtube#comment",
    "etag": "\"RmznBCICv9YtgWaaa_nWDIH1_GM/EdeFN_0T_dycmIDzkqVgskOHm6U\"",
    "id": "Ugwud1sVfboCaSWuyR54AaABAg",
    "snippet": {
    "authorDisplayName": "Gulnaz Saydullaeva",
    "authorProfileImageUrl": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-9jnflsaG9cs/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/NRge-Hcjxg8/s28-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg",
    "authorChannelUrl": "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCKoQIiDBhLNU8cpEMKPfLrQ",
    "authorChannelId": {
    "value": "UCKoQIiDBhLNU8cpEMKPfLrQ"
    },
    "videoId": "ay4MKe1u7Ec",
    "textDisplay": "А у меня не Android 4. 4. 2 у меня на моём стоит Android 5 0 1",
    "textOriginal": "А у меня не Android 4. 4. 2 у меня на моём стоит Android 5 0 1",
    "canRate": true,
    "viewerRating": "none",
    "likeCount": 1,
    "publishedAt": "2018-01-22T15:27:39.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-01-22T15:27:39.000Z"
    }
    },
    "canReply": true,
    "totalReplyCount": 0,
    "isPublic": true
}
},
{
"kind": "youtube#commentThread",
"etag": "\"RmznBCICv9YtgWaaa_nWDIH1_GM/Mdis62b6IE0Y3r5zGlGLEDj71pI\"",
"id": "UgxPYBqwH2v_tW2cQjt4AaABAg",
"snippet": {
    "videoId": "ay4MKe1u7Ec",
    "topLevelComment": {
    "kind": "youtube#comment",
    "etag": "\"RmznBCICv9YtgWaaa_nWDIH1_GM/manyPQXT2C8CQ66KYtWMWVIUsUI\"",
    "id": "UgxPYBqwH2v_tW2cQjt4AaABAg",
    "snippet": {
    "authorDisplayName": "Gulnaz Saydullaeva",
    "authorProfileImageUrl": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-9jnflsaG9cs/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/NRge-Hcjxg8/s28-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg",
    "authorChannelUrl": "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCKoQIiDBhLNU8cpEMKPfLrQ",
    "authorChannelId": {
    "value": "UCKoQIiDBhLNU8cpEMKPfLrQ"
    },
    "videoId": "ay4MKe1u7Ec",
    "textDisplay": "У меня такой же не lte",
    "textOriginal": "У меня такой же не lte",
    "canRate": true,
    "viewerRating": "none",
    "likeCount": 0,
    "publishedAt": "2018-01-16T13:32:26.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-01-16T13:32:26.000Z"
    }
    },
    "canReply": true,
    "totalReplyCount": 0,
    "isPublic": true
}
}
]
}
```

Here in `items` I am getting lot of fields in response and I am not interested in all the fields. so tried to add `fields` param in url

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?key=MY_KEY&videoId=ay4MKe1u7Ec&part=id,snippet,replies&fields=items(id,snippet(topLevelComment(snippet(textOriginal))))&maxResults=2`

Then I get only desired fields but I am not getting `nextPageToken`  without it I cant goto next page.

```
{
"items": [
{
"id": "Ugwud1sVfboCaSWuyR54AaABAg",
"snippet": {
    "topLevelComment": {
    "snippet": {
    "textOriginal": "А у меня не Android 4. 4. 2 у меня на моём стоит Android 5 0 1"
    }
    }
}
},
{
"id": "UgxPYBqwH2v_tW2cQjt4AaABAg",
"snippet": {
    "topLevelComment": {
    "snippet": {
    "textOriginal": "У меня такой же не lte"
    }
    }
}
}
]
}
```

I am calling URL using simple python script

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads'
params = {'key': API_KEY, 
        'videoId': 'ay4MKe1u7Ec', 
        'part': 'id,snippet,replies',
        'maxResults': 2,
        'fields': 'items(id,snippet(topLevelComment(snippet(textOriginal))))'}
r = requests.get(url, params=params)
print(r.json())
```

I dont know why I yuotube api is not giving me nextPageToken on using fields param. someone please tell If I am using API wrongly.

Comment: Is this for all videos (e.g. extremely popular ones too) or just some? Based on the initial example you have, I would not expect a token as there are only 2 results total.

Comment: totalResults is 2 because I am passing maxResults=2 param in url

Comment: Is the page token missing if you do not specify `maxResults`, or if you use the other method of field specification for the single nested property, e.g. [`a/b` instead of `a(b)`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#fields)?

Comment: yes then also nextpagetoken is missing. by default maxresult is 20

Comment: I think I solved this, it works on my side, try this: 'fields': 'items(id,snippet(topLevelComment(snippet(textOriginal)))),nextPageToken'}